# How to use thor in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, rspec, thor

Thor is a toolkit for building powerful command-line interfaces.

It always been used for single command line. If I want to use it in a rails project, for example:

lib/tasks/my_cli.rb

```
require "thor"

class MyCLI < Thor
  desc "hello NAME", "say hello to NAME"
  def hello(name)
    puts "Hello #{name}"
  end
end
```

Where to put the `MyCLI.start(ARGV)`?

If I put it under that file(`lib/tasks/my_cli.rb`), when I run my rspec test, it will show me the command message:

```
Commands:
  rspec help [COMMAND]   # Describe available commands or one specific command
  rspec hello NAME       # say hello to NAME
```

I don't want to see it in my `bundle exec rspec`, so I moved the `MyCLI.start(ARGV)` to `bin/rails`. It looks well. But after I do this:

```
$ ./bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0
$ [CTRL+C]
```

I saw this message:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
^CStopping ...
Exiting
Could not find command "_b".
```

What does it mean:

```
Could not find command "_b".
```

So, I don't know a best practice about how to use thor in a rails project.

Comment: I think it might be passing the `-b` that you're sending to the rails server to thor. I'm curious what the use case is here. Why would you like to use thor in a Rails project? There is certainly a way to do what you're looking for, it would be nice to have some background on the motivation here.

Comment: @fdisk Thank you. I have to run batch by hand with some options. So I used `thor`. Is there another way to do the some thing?

Comment: You can also use `rake` to launch tasks defined in `lib/tasks`, which is what I see in most Rails shops.

Comment: If use `rake`, can it take options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use method_option:
https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/wiki/Method-Options

And don't pass arguments like if it would be a normal method

```
require "thor"

class MyCLI < Thor
  desc "hello NAME", "say hello to NAME"

  method_option :name, aliases: '-b', type: :string, desc: 'It`s the named passed'

  def hello
    puts "Hello #{options[:name]}"
  end
end
```

Then use it with `thor` command:
`thor mycli:hello -b Robert`

Comment: Thank you very much. I added a module outside the class. So when I run the thor command `thor Tasks::MyCLI:hello -b any`, it said: `Could not find command "Tasks::MyCLI:hello`.

Comment: `thor tasks:mycli:hello -b Robert` use it like this [s-cho-m](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4757050/s-cho-m) and check the response as the good one if it was useful please

Comment: I am considering deprecating all of my custom rake task in favor for Thor in my rails app. Where in my rails app would I put such a file, so that thor automatically finds the command ? In many cases, I would want the rails environment to be loaded inside the Thor task context.